# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, php, cron

I'm trying to setup my crons for **Magento 2.2.2**, but nothing seems to be updating.

I have created cron in cPanel, like below, each once per minute:

```
/usr/local/bin/php /home/userishere/public_html/bin/magento cron:run | awk '{ print strftime("\%Y-\%m-\%d \%H:\%M:\%S"), $0; fflush(); }' 2>&1 >> ~/magento_cron.log

/usr/local/bin/php /home/userishere/public_html/update/cron.php | awk '{ print strftime("\%Y-\%m-\%d \%H:\%M:\%S"), $0; fflush(); }' 2>&1 >> ~/magento_cron.log

/usr/local/bin/php /home/userishere/public_html/bin/magento setup:cron:run | awk '{ print strftime("\%Y-\%m-\%d \%H:\%M:\%S"), $0; fflush(); }' 2>&1 >> ~/magento_cron.log
```

I check the **scheduale** in **PhpMyAdmin** to see this:

[image: cron]

Error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '4639-168-1-283-4639' for key 'PRIMARY', query was: `` INSERT INTO 
>   `catalog_product_index_eav_temp` (`entity_id`,`attribute_id`,`store_id`,`value`,`source_id`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?), ``

Any ideas where I'm going wrong? If you need more info please let me know.

Comment: This error means that one row  that you try to insert has an PK which already exists in db,  did you restore this db recently?

Comment: No I have not restored it, how do I find out which row?  Thank you :)

Comment: Error has updated to this

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '4639-168-1-283-4639' for key 'PRIMARY', query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_index_eav_temp` (`entity_id`,`attribute_id`,`store_id`,`value`,`source_id`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?),

Comment: @MyStackExchange did Find what was the issue? I started to have this issue as well.

Comment: Hello guys, i getting same issue with : search_tmp_5af6c92069db99_50693483. did you find any solution ?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Entry key `'4639-168-1-283-4639'`, where 4639 is `product_id`, 168 is `attribute_id`, 1 is `store_id`, 283 is `attribute_value_id` for which is getting this issue.

So if suppose attribute 168 type is `varchar`, then its values will be in `catalog_product_entity_varchar`.

Now `search` for `attribute` 168 along with `entity_id` 4639, you can see there is some values in '`value`' column.

`Edit` that row, you will see there is `more than 1 entry` `(comma separated)` for same `value_id` (here 283), just `remove all other duplicates` values from there and save it.

**Flush cache and re-run index command.**

If error comes again then again (that may come for other products as well)  check and fix in similar way.

**Not sure why magento puts duplicate values for multi-select.**

Comment: thank this is absolute right I updated entries with duplicatuion values like ` value_id: 239750
attribute_id: 152
    store_id: 0
   entity_id: 2540
       value: 3671,3671`
Once I remove the duplicate value reindex started working again!

Comment: Wow. Thank you dev_67Commerce. I was trying to figure this out for so many time. Your explanation was priceless.

Comment: Thanks to show me the light! For others I have prepared a simple script to solve the issue: https://gist.github.com/shinesoftware/9df5c706fd5c9161c36297b2509eba33

Comment: Hi I see error:  Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '16358-0-1' for key 'PRIMARY' I am confused which attribute i have to check.

Comment: i am having similar issue. there's should be a way to filter duplicated values. use before product save event maybe?

Comment: thanks for saving day :)

Comment: cool! Thanks @dev_67Commerce

Comment: mine error is little different : Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '5300-200-0' for key 'MGCP_CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_TEXT_ENTITY_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID_STORE_ID', query was: INSERT  INTO `mgcp_catalog_product_entity_text, and I checked in https://prnt.sc/AAhdMAtCSaI_ no duplicate any help please.

Answer (score 0):

maybe too late but here is a fix in indexer process of Magento, that will fix your problem (not the cause, but the "aftermath").

Method: *\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Indexer\Eav\Source::saveDataFromSelect*

Added *array_unique* for $values.

```
    private function saveDataFromSelect(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select $select, array $options)
{
    $i = 0;
    $data = [];
    $query = $select->query();
    while ($row = $query->fetch()) {
        $values = explode(',', $row['value']);
        // FIX START - multiselect attributes contains duplicated values;
        $values = array_unique($values);
        // FIX END
        foreach ($values as $valueId) {
            if (isset($options[$row['attribute_id']][$valueId])) {
                $data[] = [$row['entity_id'], $row['attribute_id'], $row['store_id'], $valueId, $row['source_id']];
                $i++;
                if ($i % 10000 == 0) {
                    $this->_saveIndexData($data);
                    $data = [];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    $this->_saveIndexData($data);
}
```

And yep, I still do not know why these duplicated values are placed/saved in Magento.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with another message, I got:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'default-0-amasty_checkout/layout_builder/layout_builder_config' for key 'CORE_CONFIG_DATA_SCOPE_SCOPE_ID_PATH', query was: INSERT INTO `core_config_data` (`scope`, `scope_id`, `path`, `value`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
```

So I opened phpmyadmin and executed the following query

```
SELECT * FROM `core_config_data` WHERE path LIKE "%amasty_checkout%"
```

Then I deleted all entries. But be careful, this will delete all your settings from this extension.

Then I executed `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` again and it worked.

You can also search for the duplicate one and delete it, but I have to reconfigure the extension anyways so I just deleted all.