# Magento 2 reindex gives error Duplicate entry

Tags: product, catalog, magento2.2.2, reindex, duplicate

I am experiencing an issue which not sure why when I try to reindex it gives the error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 
'4458-142-1-1293-4458' for key 'PRIMARY', query was: INSERT INTO 
`catalog_product_index_eav_temp` 
(`entity_id`,`attribute_id`,`store_id`,`value`,`source_id`) VALUES (?, 
?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, 
?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, 
?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?).....
```

Now the problem is I don't see a table in the Database called `catalog_product_index_eav_temp` otherwise I would delete the duplicate entry and problem would be solved.

The line that is failing is with EAV:

php bin/magento indexer:reindex
Design Config Grid index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Customer Grid index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Category Products index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Product Categories index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Product Price index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:07

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 
'4458-142-1-1293-4458' for key 'PRIMARY', query was: INSERT INTO 
`catalog_product_index_eav_temp` 
(`entity_id`,`attribute_id`,`store_id`,`value`,`source_id`) VALUES (?, 
?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, 
?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, 
?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?).....
```

Stock index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Catalog Search index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:01
Catalog Rule Product index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Catalog Product Rule index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00

Does anyone know what could be wrong and how to fix! txs.

Comment: Anyone any help? possible a duplicate https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/216720/sqlstate23000-integrity-constraint-violation-1062-duplicate-entry-magento?rq=1

Comment: I am facing the exact same problem. The error only occurs after importing products via custom script using models. After deleting all products I created a product manually for testing and there are no issues. So I assume there ist something in my import. I keep digging...

Comment: @omsta  if it helps I have found out that there were duplicate entry in `catalog_product_entity_varchar` and it was added via API So: `SELECT * FROM catalog_product_entity_varchar WHERE value='4458,4458' AND attribute_id= 142\G;   This showed me exactly what I need to see so in my case even deleting the product did not work for me. 
`

Comment: I just found my mistake. When setting the values for multiselect options (e.g. 123,124,125), I had multiple duplicates (123,123,124,125,125 and so on). A simple array_unique in the importer solved my issue. So always make sure each option value only appears once.

Comment: @omsta Yes that is correct. which file did you add array_unique? share the it please!

Comment: This happens for me after adding products for staging updates on a vanilla, unmodified instance of 2.2.7 enterprise

Comment: @JulianoVargas May i know did you solve the issue?

Comment: @zus  if you know the problematic product id select from catalog_product_entity_varchar table in entity_id column. in my case ` value_id: 1499368
attribute_id: 138
    store_id: 0
   entity_id: 23514
       value: 1304,1310,1304`     See ` 1304`  has duplicates,

Comment: @JulianoVargas FYI here is post https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/295557/57334, any help, thanks.

Comment: @JulianoVargas My table,  what i need to do https://snipboard.io/STF9Pp.jpg ?

Comment: if that is the product id giving you the error you don't seem to have a duplicate but value=0  usually id no value is specified you would have value: no_selection, what attribute is 207 ? is it size, colour try changing the value from 0 to an existing value option from your attribute 207!

Comment: @JulianoVargas any idea why this issue is occurring after a certain period of time. All my products are getting created by using default API . Does creation of products via API is the cause, is there any permanent solution or some cron toresolve it on fly

Comment: @insoftservice  That's the reason for me also we are using automation to create product via API  so when the xml is sent is being sent the item value twice.

Answer (score 4):

I have also face this issue,your error is Duplicate entry **4458-142-1-1293-4458** in your case the attribute id is **142**, go to **eav_attribute** table and check 142 attrbute **backend_type** and **entity_type_id**, for example if in 142 id your attribute backend_type is **varchar** and entity_type_id is **catalog_product**, then go to the **catalog_product_entity_varchar** and filter 142 attribute_id rows there one row with duplicate value 4458 for example it may be (123,234,4458,4458), so you need to remove one time 4458 it should be (123,234,4458), it will fix.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

4458-142-1-1293-4458

> Select * from [prefix]catalog_product_entity_varchar where
>   attribute_id=142 and entity_id=4458

Remove duplicate values from value column and then reindex

Answer (score 0):

After the upgrade of the Magento software we need to reindex the data using the standard method by shell:

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

If the reindex task produces the following error you'll need to fix the data in the product entity tables by this [script](https://gist.github.com/shinesoftware/9df5c706fd5c9161c36297b2509eba33).

Answer (score 0):

So not sure how I ended up in the same situation, but for me the fix was to re-save from the admin panel the products where the `entity_id` was included in the error message: `{entity_id}-{product attribute id}-{value 1}-{value 2}-{entity_id}`.
I did not execute delete direct queries!

I leave this post here, maybe it will help someone else.

Cheers