# Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '3-2-9' for key 'PRIMARY', query was: ALTER TABLE `catalog_category_product_index_tmp`

Tags: database, sql, magento-2.2.5, setup-upgrade

Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '3-2-9' for key 'PRIMARY', query was: ALTER TABLE `catalog_category_product_index_tmp` ADD CONSTRAINT  PRIMARY KEY (`category_id`,`product_id`,`store_id`), COMMENT='Catalog Category Product Indexer temporary table'
[image]

this error comes when I run the setup:upgrade command in Magento 2
please make some suggestions to get rid of this error

Comment: can you show your schema file?

Comment: i could not understand which file i show u..?

Comment: installschema.php file

Comment: please tell me which location exist this file...?

Comment: you said error comes start of schema creation/update right? then you must be creating table right? , file will be at `app/code/Vendor/Module/Setup/` folder

Answer (score 0):

Check-in which module has stuck the setup:upgrade and apply one of the solutions welpixel :  [How to fix Integrity constraint violation](https://support.weltpixel.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000594454-How-to-fix-Integrity-constraint-violation-when-upgrading-Magento-from-2-1-x-to-2-2-x)

or go in your database and remove the duplicated manually, following the logic @dev_67Commerce suggested : [Duplicate entry - Magento 2
Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/216720/sqlstate23000-integrity-constraint-violation-1062-duplicate-entry-magento?rq=1),

Comment: error come start of schema creation/update

Comment: i mean wich module get stucked

Comment: see my updated question

Comment: Follow the second link i showed to you