# Magento 2: 500 error on save products in admin

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, admin-panel

I am experiencing the 500 error on product save. Previously it shows me the memory exhausted error in log but after increasing memory limit I am seeing error in exception log like below.

`SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '16358-0-1' for key 'PRIMARY'`

I have found one answer [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/216720/sqlstate23000-integrity-constraint-violation-1062-duplicate-entry-magento) but in my case i don't know which duplicate value i should search for.